# Swift 3 UITableView cell seperator disappears when i remove cell subviews

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview

I have an array type of string arrays and I print it to `tableView` within for loop.I know its a bad practice loop inside `cellForRowAt indexPath`: function but I don't have any solution.My Problem is every time I move my `tableview` on simulator,i insert more subviews on existing ones.it overwrites older ones and to prevent i use

```
for view in cell.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

but it deletes my cell seperators with my older cell labels.How can i remove only cell data not my seperator.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell
    //print(cell.subviews)
    for view in cell.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }


    for i in 0..<globalHeaderStructArray.count{
        var newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:xCoordination, y:10, width:Double(globalHeaderStructArray[i].width)!, height:30.0))
        newLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 17.0)
        newLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        newLabel.text = "\(globalDataArray[indexPath.row][i])"

        var scrollview = UIScrollView(frame: cell.bounds)
        scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width:cell.bounds.width * 5, height:cell.bounds.height) // will be 5 times as wide as the cell
        scrollview.isPagingEnabled = true

        cell.contentView.addSubview(scrollview)
        cell.addSubview(newLabel)
        xCoordination += Double(globalHeaderStructArray[i].width)!
    }
    xCoordination = 0.0

    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `tag` to your label and `scrollView` object and check that inside loop like this.

```
for view in cell.subviews {
    if view.tag == 101 || view tag == 102 {
        view.removeFromSuperview() 
    }
}


for i in 0..<globalHeaderStructArray.count{
    var newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:xCoordination, y:10, width:Double(globalHeaderStructArray[i].width)!, height:30.0))
    newLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 17.0)
    newLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    newLabel.text = "\(globalDataArray[indexPath.row][i])"
    newLabel.tag = 101

    var scrollview = UIScrollView(frame: cell.bounds)
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width:cell.bounds.width * 5, height:cell.bounds.height) // will be 5 times as wide as the cell
    scrollview.isPagingEnabled = true
    scrollview.tag = 102

    cell.contentView.addSubview(scrollview)
    cell.addSubview(newLabel)
    xCoordination += Double(globalHeaderStructArray[i].width)!
}
```

**Tips:** It is batter if you use interface builder to design your cell instead of adding `UI` element at run time.

Comment: How about we _never_ encourage the usage of ambiguous tags unless 100% absolute necessary (which is extremely rare and usually at fault for legacy architecture issues)? If you need a reference, use pointers.....